# Some .zshrc settings aren't loaded

Tags: macos, zsh, fzf

I have a MacBook with Iterm2 with Zshell (zsh) and one of the add-ons I have is the command line fuzzy finder (fzf), but despite being added to my .zshrc it doesn't work. If I manually load it with `source ~/.fzf.zsh` it works, and if I then reload my .zshrc `source ~/.zshrc` it doesn't work again.

**What could be the reason?**

*Here's most of my .zshrc file (see the line: # add fuzzy find):*

```sh
if [[ -r "${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/p10k-instant-prompt-${(%):-%n}.zsh" ]]; then
  source "${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/p10k-instant-prompt-${(%):-%n}.zsh"
fi

# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
# export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

# add fuzzy find
[ -f ~/.fzf.zsh ] && source ~/.fzf.zsh

# add syntax highlighting
export ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_HIGHLIGHTERS_DIR=/usr/local/share/zsh-syntax-highlighting/highlighters
source $(brew --prefix)/share/zsh-syntax-highlighting/zsh-syntax-highlighting.zsh

# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH="/Users/xxxx/.oh-my-zsh"

ZSH_THEME="powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k"

plugins=(git)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

DEFAULT_USER=`whoami`

# To customize prompt, run `p10k configure` or edit ~/.p10k.zsh.
[[ ! -f ~/.p10k.zsh ]] || source ~/.p10k.zsh
alias pip=/usr/local/bin/pip3
```

Comment: Does something later in the file undo something that `.fzf.zsh` does? What happens if you move that code to the bottom of `.zshrc`?

Comment: Omg that solved it! Make it an answer so I can upvote it

Comment: Wonder which it could be though. Non of the commands look problematic to me

Comment: What exactly does `~/.fzf.zsh` do?

Comment: It could be something in `oh-my-zsh.sh` or `.p10k.zsh` that causes the problem.

Comment: With Fuzzy Finder if you hit CTRL+R you get a nice search function through your command history. I strongly recommend it: https://github.com/junegunn/fzf

Comment: That's not what I meant: what commands are in `.fzf.zsh`? If it's just the keybinding that stops working, I wouldn't be at all surprised if `oh-my-zsh.sh` is simply rebinding it.

Comment: It does indeed to rebinding. I guess that was it then. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something you do in `.zshrc` following `source ~/.fzf.zsh` breaks it. Make sure `~/.fzf.zsh` occurs *after* that, most easily accomplished by moving it to the end of the file.

Comment: Thanks!! Some trial and error showed `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh` to be the problem. I'm not sure what it does, but I decided to move it all the way to the top.

Comment: It does a *lot* of stuff, which is why I don't use it myself. I look through it occasionally for ideas to add manually to my configuration.